# Convert specific string to dateTime in dataTable Row

Tags: c#, string, datetime, datetime-parsing

I am trying to convert a specific String to a DateTime which is contained in a DataTable. But for some reason not quite working. I have tried a few combinations. The thing is that the string actually contains " " surrounding the date.

So cell in DataTable containing value (including double quotes)
**"2014-08-08 08:00:00"**

My code iterates through all of it and tries to convert it into a DateTime (need it as doing a bulkCopy.WriteToServer(datatable) to SQL Server.

```
  //Fix up default values and remove double quotes from field in order to convert to date
  if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
  {
      for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
      {
          dt.Rows[i]["usagestartdate"] = 
              dt.Rows[i]["usagestartdate"].ToString() == "" ?
              DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2014) : 
              Convert.ToDateTime((dt.Rows[i]["invoiceid"].ToString().Replace("'", "")));
          dt.Rows[i]["usagestartdate"] = 
              dt.Rows[i]["usageend"].ToString() == "" ? 
              DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2014) : 
              Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["usageend"].ToString());
      }
  }
```

I get the error on the first line inside the loop.

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Any ideas how to make the cast work properly?

Comment: Just a sidenote: DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2014) looks... interesting. Why not just use DateTime.MinValue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing single quote(`'`) with double quote(`"`).

That's why when you write `Replace("'", "")` part, it doesn't replace with anything because your string doesn't have *any* single quotes. That's the reason one solution might be change from `Replace("'", "")` to `Replace("\"", "")` in your code.

#### But here an another way

Since you are using [`Convert.ToDateTime(string)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e(v=vs.110).aspx), this method uses your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) settings by default. And none of culture have a standard date and time format with double quoted string as `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`. That's why, you need to use custom date and time parsing with [`DateTime.TryParseExact` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) for example like;

```
string s = "\"2014-08-08 08:00:00\"";
string format = "\\\"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss\\\"";
DateTime date;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    Console.WriteLine (date);
}
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/WuPWxG)</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dtRows[i], "yyyy/MM/DD HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: That's not works. First, it is `dt.Rows[i]["invoiceid"]`, not `dtRows[i]`. Second, the string rounded with double quotes, that's why you need to change your format. Third, there is no `DD` as a format. Fourth, date separator is `-` not `/` in his example.

Answer (score 0):

Just realised I did a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> and was still not covering the double quotes, just single. Replaced with

```
dt.Rows[i]["usagestartdate"] = dt.Rows[i]["usagestartdate"].ToString() == "" ? 
                               DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2014) : 
                               Convert.ToDateTime((dt.Rows[i]["usagestartdate"].ToString().Replace("\"", "")));
```

And all working now!